# Make a separate list of selected content

Tags: views, nodes

Hi I am very new to Drupal. I want to make a restricted list of contents to show in a view. By default a view of certain content type brings all of the contents in it which I don't want. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Nodequeues](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) to accomplish this really effectively.